# GraphqQL Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have tried looking at other articles on SO related to this question, but I am unable to resolve this issue.

I have a graphql api and in my component on the UI side, I am calling it as such

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const leaders = graphQLClient.request(GetLeadersQuery)
    if(leaders && leaders.leaders) {
      let leadersList = JSON.parse(leaders.leaders)
      setLeaders(leadersList)
    }
  }, [leaders])
```

On the server side, this  looks like this

```
leaders: (_parent, args, _context) => {
      return (JSON.stringify({
        name:"Jane Dooe"
      }))
```

This is the query that I am using

```
  query {
    leaders
  }
```

Now everytime, my client side code is hit, I see the following error in my terminal.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

My use case is very simple and yet , I am unable to see why I am encountering this error.

**Update**
On my client side, I tried doing  the following, just to make sure that I am resolving the promises, but  I am still getting the same result.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function getLeaders(){
      const leaders = await graphQLClient.request(GetLeadersQuery)
      console.log({ leaders })
      if (leaders && leaders.leaders) {
        let leadersList = JSON.parse(leaders.leaders)
        setLeaders(leadersList)
      }
    }

    getLeaders()
  }, [])
```

On the server side  I am using

1. NextJS
2. apollo-server-micro

On the client side I am using

1. React
2. graphql-request

Can you please help ?

Thanks

Comment: Where you see the error ? on the gql server or in the next js server ? or in the browser ?

Comment: I see this  error whenever this NextJS Graphql endpoint is hit. I see on this terminal.

Comment: If you are seeing this in the terminal then maybe there is some problem in your server side code. `leaders: (_parent, args, _context) => {
      return (JSON.stringify({
        name:"Jane Dooe"
      }))`

First I don't see any closing brackets here. Second usually I see this error when after sending response from the server, some codes are still waiting to be executed. So, server is not finding the required "headers" to execute that code. It would be helpful if you post the server side code in detail.